# Firebase redirect to webpage after successful password change

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web-applications, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase in my web app with Ionic and I would like to redirect the user to a specific page (the login page, in my case) after he change the password successfully.
At the moment, when the user clicks on the password reset link, he is redirected on another browser page that says that he has successfully changed the password.

[image]

I would like to redirect him to a page of my web app, after changing the password.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to pass a continue URL via `ActionCodeSettings` to redirect the user back to the app:

```
var actionCodeSettings = {
  // After password reset, the user will be give the ability to go back
  // to this page.
  url: 'https://www.example.com/afterPasswordReset',
  handleCodeInApp: false
};
firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
  .then(function() {
    // Password reset email sent.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Error occurred. Inspect error.code.
  });
```

Learn more about `ActionCodeSettings` and passing state in redirect:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions

You can also build your own custom landing page here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: with. your solution , does it work on the web? when i implement this solution on the web, i got the error `missing domain in the continueUrl`.

Comment: did this work for you?

Comment: here are list of possible errors and their reasons.
This is official firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#sendpasswordresetemail